# Error: Unknown provider: $animateProvider from ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am getting Unknown provider: $animateProvider from ngAnimate error in my angular.js file. i checked for the solution online and it says to change the version of angular.animate.js file. do i also have to change the version of angular.js file. i am currently using 1.0.2 version. I chnaged my angular.animate.js version from 1.0.2 to 1.2.6. But error is still coming. here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name='myform' ng-init="step = 1">

<div ng-show="step==1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"> <h3 class="bounceInDown">I am</h3> </div>
<div ng-form='step1form'>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton repeat-animation" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 4">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
Self-employed Professional
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 2">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
Self-employed Business
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="step==2">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6"> <h3>I need a loan of</h3> </div>
<div ng-form='step2form'>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
1 lacs
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
2 lacs
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
3 lacs
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
5 lacs
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
10 lacs
</button>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton" ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid" ng-click="step = 3">
<img src="SoundCloud.png" alt="Save icon"/>
<br/>
More than 10 lacs
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<button  ng-click="step = 1">Prev</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my js file

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
     $scope.name = '';    

    $scope.items = []; 
    $timeout(function(){
      for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        $scope.items.push(i);
      }
    }, 10);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you use the same version, if you're using animate 1.2.6 you also need to use angular 1.2.6:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

FYI: While you're in the progress of upgrading you might as well try and upgrade to the latest legacy version which at the time of writing this is 1.2.29 or even the latest stable 1.5.0